# How do I disable a launchd service I no longer have the plist for?

Tags: macos, launchd

I delete an app that had some service running through launchd. Now launchd complains all the time in the console for not being able to launch the service:

```
19/02/15 08:50:28,589 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.sovapps.launchAtLoginHelper[16732]) Could not find and/or execute program specified by service: 149: Could not find a bundle of the given identifier through LaunchServices: com.sovapps.launchAtLoginHelper
19/02/15 08:50:28,589 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.sovapps.launchAtLoginHelper) Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

Since I no longer have the plist file, I can’t simply unload the service. How do I make launchd forget about the service?

Comment: Are You sure the plist is not located in LaunchAgents/LaunchDaemons directories?

Comment: Yes, pretty sure.

Comment: Have you looked in /System/Library/LaunchAgents and /System/Library/LaunchDaemons, as well as in ~/Library/LaunchAgents? You should also check System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login items. The launched daemon is from a SovApps app (www.sovapps.com). Perhaps you can contact them for more information. In addition, you may need to reinstall the app you deleted to see if there is an option in the apps' preferences to disable launch at startup.

Comment: Reinstalling & disabling the launch-at-login option was a nice solution (if not very Unixy :-), thank you.